# No sound from speaker on LG gram 2023 (i7-1360P)

Tags: sound, alsa, 23.04

Just bought a LG Gram 16Z90R-G.AD78F EVO that is the brand new Lg Gram with new i7-1360P, instead of previous i7-1260P (my previous laptop, no sound issue).

After installing Ubuntu cinnamon 23.04, everything works well except I can't have any sound from the speaker, it work well on HDMI output or jack, but switching to internal speaker don't output any sound.

I've tried to follow a lot of tutorial on the web, like this [one](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=153813)

```
$ uname -a 
Linux udol 6.2.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  6 07:48:48 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ dmesg | grep sof
[    2.683941] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040100
[    2.684125] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    2.684142] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.684596] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040100
[    4.183953] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.266023] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    4.284380] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[    4.284384] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[    4.284387] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
[    4.284968] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    4.284970] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.284975] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[    4.397123] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:2:0-57864
[    4.397129] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.402583] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Topology: ABI 3:22:1 Kernel ABI 3:23:0
[    4.497861] input: sof-hda-dsp Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input12
[    4.497912] input: sof-hda-dsp Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input13
[    4.497954] input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input14
[    4.497993] input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input15
[    4.498028] input: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0/input16
```

```
$ inxi -A 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-20-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
```

System info [here](https://termbin.com/gzozo), and [also-info](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=4f783fcf9344347d078dac06fb440d18a78c6454)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have a similar problem with the 14-inch model of LG Gram 2023. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: No solution for now, still on the earphone or hdmi output ...

Comment: Same with 16T90R-K.ADB9U1, 1360P, Ubuntu 22.04, ALSA v: k5.19.0-46-generic, PipeWire v: 0.3.48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is solved.
Please have a look:

https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?331130-Fixing-ALC298-audio-(no-sound-from-speakers)

The solution relies on executing a number of `hda-verb` (from `alsa-tools`) commands to reconfigure the HD audio codec .

```sh
sudo apt install -y alsa-tools
wget https://github.com/joshuagrisham/galaxy-book2-pro-linux/raw/main/sound/necessary-verbs.sh

chmod +x necessary-verbs.sh
sudo ./necessary-verbs.sh
```

If it works for you, you may want to run it on boot like this:

```sh
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/audio-fix-alc298.service
[Unit]
Description=Run internal speaker fix script at startup
After=getty.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/necessary-verbs.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF
```

Notes:

- hda-verb requires root at least on Ubuntu 22.04
- as usual you should inspect the untrusted shell script

Comment: Maybe the form is not probably the best, the solution is just working perfectly, month of constraint removed, Thanks @Alex !! Just need to install alsa-tools (apt-get install alsa-tools) and the script make my speakers works !!

Comment: I addded some details, although for some reason I couldn't make it work on my 16T90R-K.ADB9U1 using the same ALC298.

Comment: after this,The left channel volume is higher than right

Comment: I can confirm that left/right balance need to be updated right:80% left:100%